# what is the error ? and how can i solve it?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I am learning flutter. i have made one app name chat x(title). the code is below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Chat X'),
    ),
  body: Card(child: Column(children: <Widget>[
    Text('hey! this one is new');
  ],),),
  ),
);
 }
 }
```

when ever i want to debug this code i get this error

> Expected to find ']'.

Comment: try flutter clean. may be you got that error because of caches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `;` from `Text('hey! this one is new');` or you can place a `,` if you want to have more widgets inside `Column`

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Chat X'),
        ),
        body: Card(child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            Text('hey! this one is new'),
            Text('hey! this one is second new'),
          ],),),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shoud not have the ; after the Text widget. Like this:

```
Text('hey! this one is new')
```